# Form file upload protected properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I can not handle file upload forms. Sorry if it is a dummy question, but:
If I use `'files' => 'true'` or `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` in the Forms open tag I get an object with protected properties. How can I handle the originalName, mimeType etc.. in my app?

Answer (score 0):

To handle file uploads you do:

On your view:

```
<form action="{{ UR::route('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="photo" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!">
</form>
```

Or in blade:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => UR::route('upload'))) }}
    {{ Form::file('photo'); }}
    {{ Form::submit('Upload!'); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then on your controller you can:

```
$name = Input::get('photo')->getFileName();
$size = Input::get('photo')->getClientSize();

Input::get('photo')->move(public_path().'/uploads', $name);
```

You can find a full list of methods in the file `vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile.php`